# Filter nested array via other array elements

Tags: swift

I am struggling with filtering an array of objects which have a nested arrays of different objects.

Eg. I have an array of objects:

```
class Form {
   let name: String
   let lasname: String
   let roles: [Rule]

   // ... init etc.
}

class Rule {
   let rule: String

   // ... init etc.
}
```

Initialized array would looks like:

```
var forms = [Form]()
let firstRoles: [Rule] = [Rule(rule: "First"), Rule(rule: "Second")]
let secondRoles: [Rule] = [Rule(rule: "Third"), Rule(rule: "Second")]

forms.append(Form(name: "Test1", lastname: "Test2", roles: firstRoles))
forms.append(Form(name: "Test3", lastname: "Test4", roles: secondRoles))
```

And now I need to filter `forms` via **Keys**.

`Keys`:

```
let keyRoles: [Rule] = [Rule(rule: "First"), Rule(rule: "Second")]
```

After filtering 2 element array `forms` I should recived only first becouse both of the rules match the pattern.

The code for filtering:

```
forms.filter { (form) in Bool in 
   return form.roles.contains(where: { (rule) -> Bool in 
      keyRoles.contains(rule)
   })
}
```

Will return nothing, an empty array. 
Any ideas what Am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using contains which will return if any one of the keyRole matches form role. But your expected result is all `keyRoles` must match.

```
let filtered = forms.filter { (form) -> Bool in
    for kr in keyRoles {
        if !form.roles.contains(where: { (r) -> Bool in
            return r.rule == kr.rule
        }) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Note: if `keyRoles` is empty it won't filter anything (forms == filtered)

Answer (score 1):

You code has a problem, you are checking whether `rule` (which is a references) exists in the `keyRoles` array and that will always return false since `keyRoles` array has different references than in forms. Because you've created objects instead of reusing them, although the content is the same but they are in different memory space.

you've inserted Rule objects in the form that are different in `keyRoles` array

Either it can be solved if you use `keyRoles` as below

```
let keyRoles: [firstRoles, secondRoles]
```

Or while checking the

```
keyRoles.contains(rule)
```

You need to add predicate so that content of rule matches the content of the other rule. i.e. compare the internal data structure instead of comparing the references. Something like below

```
let arr = forms.filter { (form) -> Bool in
  return form.roles.contains(where: { (rule1) -> Bool in
    keyRoles.contains(where: { (rule2) -> Bool in
      rule1.rule == rule2.rule
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right about references. Now I've realized the same - How can I get the correct result while filtering via references which won't be the same, Thank you for pointing on this!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a *pretty good practice* for your case (when using [contains(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) method), which is conforming to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) Protocol:

> A type that can be compared for value equality.

Note that when working with `contains(where:)`, the element of the array should be *equatables*, so you could let your `Rule` class to be an equatable:

```
class Rule: Equatable {
    let rule: String

    static func ==(lhs: Rule, rhs: Rule) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rule == rhs.rule
    }

    // ... init etc.
}
```

Thus, you'd be able to implement:

```
let filteredForms = forms.filter { form -> Bool in
    for rule in keyRoles {
        return (form.roles.contains(rule)) ? true : false
    }

    return false
}
```

`filteredForms` should contains the desired result.

Obviously, by following this approach, rules instances would be "equatables":

```
let rule1 = Rule(rule: "First")
let rule2 = Rule(rule: "First")

rule1 == rule2 // true
rule1 != rule2 // false
```